# Centering Figure (sgame) Correctly

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

I am currently using Martin J. Osborne's package sgame to draw some matrix form games. However, I have a problem: I cannot center the matrices properly when adding extra rows to the matrix. The next picture shows that, when using \hbox to add an extra row, the centering is bad because LaTex seems not to consider the extra row given by \hbox (when \hbox is not used, the centering is correct). Therefore, the centering of the second matrix is ugly:

[image]

This is a MWE that reproduces this behaviour.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amsthm}
\usepackage{sgame}

\renewcommand{\gamestretch}{1.5}
\gamemathtrue
\def\hangUnder#1{\hbox to 0pt {\raisebox{-5mm}[0pt][0pt]{#1}}}
\irpawcgltrue
\irplwcgltrue

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
  & $L$ & $R$\\
$H$ & 0,1 & 0,0\\
$L$ & 0,0 & 0,1
\end{game}
\medskip
\caption{Matching Pennies}\label{MPS6}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
  & $L$ & $R$\\
$U$ & 0,1 & 0,0\hbox to 0pt{\hspace{7pt} $p$}\\
$D$ & 0,0\hangUnder{\hspace{-13pt}$q$} & 0,1\hangUnder{\hspace{-20pt}$1-q$} \hbox to 0pt{\hspace{7pt} $1-p$}
\end{game}
\medskip
\caption{Matching Pennies}\label{MPS3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What I would like is that the hboxes are considered when computing the horizontal center of the figure. Analogously, using \hangunder reduces the space between the figure and the caption unless I manually add some arbitrary vertical space with \vspace. I would like \hangunder to be considered when doing the computations, to avoid manually adding a vertical space. Thank you all! :)

Comment: `\hbox` isn't a command supported in latex documents use `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` to make a 0 width box

Comment: Thank you; I never understood what it means to be supported or not; but I'll keep your advise in mind and I'll change the hboxes. Though useful, your suggestion does not solve my question.

Comment: well in this case I just mean that `\hbox` not being centred by `\centering` and similar latex constructs is by design

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your explanation. However, \makebox does not seem to do the trick I need. :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider just setting these constructions using a regular `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%

  \begin{tabular}{ r @{} c | c | c | }
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player 2} \\
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$L$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$R$} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    & $H$ & 0,1 & 0,0 \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \raisebox{\arraystretch\dimexpr.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Player 1~} & $L$ & 0,0 & 0,1 \\
    \cline{3-4}
  \end{tabular}

  \caption{Matching pennies}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{ r @{} c | c | c | l }
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player 2} \\
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$L$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$R$} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    & $H$ & 0,1 & 0,0 & $p$ \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \raisebox{\arraystretch\dimexpr.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Player 1~} & $L$ & 0,0 & 0,1 & $1-p$ \\
    \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$q$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{$1-q$}}
  \end{tabular}

  \caption{Matching loonies}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: After waiting for a week; and given the absence of new replies, I accept yours as the best one (since it generates the desired output). However, I have chosen to keep the bad alignment to stick to the package I am using and not having to use tikz.